# Styling the actionbar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-styles

i'am following the documentation on [developers.android][1] site to customize my action bar.

the problem is that the action bar doesn't accept the style i made.
this is the file 14/style (i'am testing on 4.3 android version device):

```
<resources>

    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="AppTheme"
        parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_color</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

and this is a part of my manifest :

```
<application

        android:name="com.fakher.actualitefoot.controller.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

what must i do ? note : i'm using the support library, the application support api-9
[1]: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#AndroidThemes

Comment: Go for [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html), don't trust the documentation on android devs

Comment: @Florin T it's generating this error : <br/> >     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: is your activity extending ActionBarActivity ? Try to put android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  on each activity. //ignore my previous answer.

Comment: no it extends 'AppCompatActivity'

Comment: if you look closely `<item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>` background should be a drawable not color!

Comment: @Florin T no it didn't work :(

Comment: @ Muhammad Babar is there any way to put a color ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I designed my Action Bar like the below:
I created an **custom_action_bar.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#526e83"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ContactImageId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CTS"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="CTS"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/UserName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Welcome: HKH"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

then in onCreate in my activity i called this method:

```
public void customActionBar() {

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
    actionBar.setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#526e83")));
    View cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(cView);
}
```

I hope this may help you in finding what you want

Comment: and my activity should extends from what class ??

Comment: Your activity should `extends ActionBarActivity`

Comment: thx it's work, but it's a lot of code !! i just want to use the default action bar with some modification !

Comment: Can you show any design or example for what you want? And I will try as much as I can to reduce the above code for what you need...

Comment: Thx i customized my action bar as i wanted to be. but i just asking why i just don't chage it by styles.xml file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style your actionBar there is another easy way to do it.

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#8B58A3")));

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.titleview, null);

    TextView frag1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.titleFragment1);
    frag1.setTypeface(yourdesiredFont);

    actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

and in your textview add whatever style or items you want to add to the actionBar and it will work great.

Comment: and my activity should extends from what class ??

Comment: @SaHa like this "public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity"